# Creating new Customised field so it appear in Sales Order import scenario in Order Nbr.> section

Tags: acumatica

I would like to create a new customised field on the Sales Order summary screen so that it appears in the Import Scenario for Sales Order in the Order Nbr.-> Section. Is it possible?

Like by default we have **Order Nbr.-> Order Nbr** or **Order Nbr.-> Customer Order**

The final goal is to be able to select this newly added field in "Order Nbr. ->" prefix in the Import Scenario.

The reason I need this field is that I am creating import Scenarios to import the Salesforce Opportunity as Sales Order in Acumatica. For this, I have to create two Import scenarios, One for Order Summary and 2nd for Order details as the data in Salesforce is in two different tables.

Currently I am using the “Customer Order” field on the Order summary to store the Opportunity ID and then in my 2nd import Scenario, I am using  Order Nbr. ->Customer Order field to pickup the relevant Opportunity where the details should be imported. Client would like to use Customer Order for the actual Customer Order number so I am thinking of either using the External Reference or a new field to import the Opportunity ID.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect fields with the "Order Nbr. ->" prefix in their names, those are the columns found inside the Order Nbr. selector drop-down:
[image]

Any custom field added for the SOOrder DAC and placed somewhere on the Sales Orders header form should be accessible for an integration scenario. For example, the Custom Text Field I added for Sales Orders was immediately accessible within the Import Scenarios screen:

[image]
[image]

There is nothing complicated in adding the External Reference and a new custom field in the Order Nbr. selector drop-down:
[image]

You should simply add the External Reference and a new custom field to the Customize Selector Columns dialog and, if needed, reorder the columns:
[image]

And to enable searching by the External Reference and a new custom field within the Order Nbr. selector drop-down, you should add CustomerRefNbr and custom field name in the **GridProperties -> FastFilterFields** property of the Order Nbr. selector:
[image]

Comment: Another similar question but not related to the above issue. 
I would like to add the Owner Name ( Employee Name) on the PO Screen in the PO Order Nbr. lookup screen. I tried to manually add the following in the Data Class for OrdNbr but  it didn't bring the Employee name in the lookup screen.

typeof(PX.Objects.CR.CREmployee.acctName)

Can you please help or let me know if i am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: @A.Ahmed, for "*another similar question but not related to the above issue*" it's always better to start a new thread. I would also greatly appreciate if you accept my answer following the steps at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: here is the link for new thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267361/adding-owner-name-in-the-purchase-order-lookup-screen/47268057?noredirect=1#comment81493199_47268057