# Adding Owner Name in the Purchase Order Lookup screen

Tags: acumatica

I would like to add the Owner Name (on the PO Screen) in the Purchase Order>Order Nbr. field lookup screen. I tried to manually add the following in the Data Class for OrdNbr but it didn't bring the Employee name in the lookup screen. Can you please help or let me know if i am missing something.
Here is the full code i am trying(screenshot attached)

```
[PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderType),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderNbr),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorRefNbr),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderDate),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.status),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorID),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorID_Vendor_acctName),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorLocationID),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.curyID),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.curyOrderTotal),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.sOOrderType),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.sOOrderNbr),
typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderDesc),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.CREmployee.acctCD),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.CREmployee.bAccountID),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.CREmployee.acctName))]
```

Many  Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH4ra.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Since POOrder.employeeID has a **PXSelector** attribute on its definition:

[image]

And this Selector has a **DescriptionField** assigned:

[image]

On this case you can add Owner name by adding this line of code to your CacheExtension file(This will obtain that DescriptionField for the EmployeeID field):

```
public abstract class employeeID_CREmployee_acctName : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
```

See Snippet below:

```
namespace PX.Objects.PO
{
    [PXNonInstantiatedExtension]
    public class PO_POOrder_ExistingColumn : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder>
    {
        #region OwnerName
        public abstract class employeeID_CREmployee_acctName : PX.Data.IBqlField
        { }
        #endregion

        #region OrderNbr    
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]

        [PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderType),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderNbr),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorRefNbr),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderDate),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.status),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.employeeID),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.PO_POOrder_ExistingColumn.employeeID_CREmployee_acctName),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorID),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorID_Vendor_acctName),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorLocationID),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.curyID),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.curyOrderTotal),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.sOOrderType),
            typeof(PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.sOOrderNbr))]
        public string OrderNbr { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Please notice that in case the **POOrder.EmployeeID** field would not have the "**DescriptionField**" set on the **PXSelector** Definition, you would have to modify the PXSelector of the **OrderNbr** to add a **LeftJoin** on the Desired Table(**CREmployee** on this case) so you could use the desired fields and add them to the **PXCustomizeSelectorColumns** attribute.

Comment: I tried the above and it had added the Employee ID and Name in the Lookup screen after i just published the above Code entered in the "POOrderCache" DAC Extension (without making any change in the Selector Column ). Now i also need to include PO "Description" field (OrderDesc) , In the "Selector Column " for OrderNbr field, after i added the Datafield OrderDesc, on closing i am getting error "cannot find the BQL field: PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.employeeID_CREmployee_AccName.

Please help.

Comment: Please notice you need to use DAC Extension, typeof(PX.Objects.PO.PO_POOrder_ExistingColumn.employeeID_CREmployee_acctName), on that error message you posted seems like you are using the original DAC, POOrder.employeeID_CREmployee_acctName instead.

Comment: Below are the steps I followed

1. Created a Customisation Project

2. Add Screen> Customise Existing screen>Selected Purchase Order Screen(PO.30.10.00)

3. Selected Code> click on + to add new code

4. Selected File Template >DAC Extension

5. Selected Base dac>PX.Objects.PO.POOrderEntry+POOrderCache

6. Replace the code starting from namespace to the one you send me in the above answer

7. Published the Current Project 


After this i tried and both Employee ID and name fields were there.

Comment: can you please let me know if i am missing anything or did it wrong

Comment: Try these steps instead:  1) Create a Customization Project.   2) Click on "Data Access" Section.  3) Then, Click on the plus sign(+)  and select "PX.Objects.PO.POOrder", click ok.   4) Click on "Add Field" and Select "Change Attibute of Base Field".  5) Select "OrderNbr" field and click ok.   6)Click  on "Selector Columns", then click on "Add Columns", locate both Owner(EmployeeID) and Description (OrderDesc), click ok and Save. 7) Click on Data Access section, on the right side locate  POOrder and click  Convert To Extension, this will move the file to the Code section, then replace code.

Comment: Let me know if this fix your issue.

Comment: I followed the steps and both Description and Employee name fields are available now but when i am trying to add another column using UI, i am getting the same error. I believe once this customisation is published,  i need to add the code for adding any new column in the Data Access. is this correct?

Comment: After Customization is published, If you refer to add Columns to the same PXSelector: you can add columns to the PXSelector directly on the Code file. (No need to use the UI, just get their names and add them on the Code file).     If you mean adding new column to the POOrder, then yes you can add it using the Data Access Section.